# How to combine 2 columns in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, gantt-chart

[Hello! This is a CSV table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpPha.png)I was trying to combine CSV output with Python to create Gantt Charts. Each column in CSV file means a date time, for example `start1` is the hours and the `start2` - minutes. After that, i use `pd.to_datetime(data["start1"], format="%H")` for the proper formatting. Same to the `start2`.
And here is the thing: how can i combine both this columns in pandas DataFrame to get one column in `"%H-%M"` format? Like data["start"]. Here is the [data.head() output and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYr2o.png) code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import timedelta

#import data
data = pd.read_csv('TEST.csv')

#convert data str to "datetime" data
data["start1"] = pd.to_datetime(data["start1"], format="%H")
data["start2"] = pd.to_datetime(data["start2"], format="%M")
data["end1"] = pd.to_datetime(data["end1"], format="%H")
data["end2"] = pd.to_datetime(data["end2"], format="%M")
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `data.head()` so we can see the hour and minute formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
data["start"] = pd.to_datetime(data["start1"].astype(str).str.pad(2, fillchar="0") + 
                               data["start2"].astype(str).str.pad(2, fillchar="0"), 
                               format="%H%M")
data["end"] = pd.to_datetime(data["end1"].astype(str).str.pad(2, fillchar="0") + 
                             data["end2"].astype(str).str.pad(2, fillchar="0"), 
                             format="%H%M")
```

Comment: Now i'm receiving a TypeError: cannot add DatetimeArray and DatetimeArray. Maybe i need to make the summary with timedelta method?

Comment: What is the output of `data.dtypes`?

Comment: Here's the thing: i need to work with MathCAD Prime CSV Output, put this program can work with digits only. So, when i mean 12:00 for example, it's going to 12 to column "start1" and 0 to "start2". In the end, i expect new column start with "%H:%M formatting. I believe datatime + timedetla scheme should work. When i formatting these columns to %H and %M their format has to be datatime. I hope this makes it more clear

Comment: I include the data.head() output and a csv table

Answer (score 0):

Before you change the data types to date time you can add an additional column like this:

```py
data["start"] = data["start1"] + '-' + data["start2"]
data["start"] = pd.to_datetime(data["start"], format="%H-%M")
# then do the other conversions.
```